# $PM<SourceName>@TableName variable alternative for Redshift Source in Informatica

Tags: amazon-redshift, informatica

I am creating Informatica mapping with Redshift table as source and I want to pass 'source table name' in one expression, but I see there is no built-in variable $PM@TableName available for Redshift source. How do we get source table name at runtime using any alternative approach?

Comment: Are you using it correct format - like, if source instance is 'Customers', then you should use $PMCustomers@TableName, if source uses a mapplet named mplt_cust then it should be $PMmplt_cust.Customers@TableName. And you are using them in output port.

Comment: Yes, I am giving the exact same name but it seems this type of ($PM<SourceName>@TableName) built-in variable is not available in case of Redshift source. If you use Teradata or some other database source, you will get it in built-in variable list. And since I am changing source from Teradata to Redshift, I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: i am curious. are you using odbc or separate driver?